# How to set credentials property in ReactJs fetch by fetch-interceptor

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project in which we have to include cookies for each service call from frontend (ReactJs) due to authentication. However, all our service calls are implemented by fetch API. Because fetch API does not include cookies by default, we have to add the configuration "credentials: 'include'" to where fetch API is used. It is not maintainable to manually do it everywhere in our code, so we decide to use fetch-interceptor plug in. My code looks like

```
fetchIntercept.register({
  request: function (url, config) {
    config.credentials = 'include';
    return [url, config];
  },
  ...
};
```

However, all fetch functions stop working after the change. Here is the message we found in  Chrome developer console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to fetch login user info:
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'credentials' of undefined

I searched online about how to set configuration in fetch-interceptor, but few examples are available. Could someone provide us an example how to set configuration correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see this hasn't been answered in 2 years. Hopefully you have solved the problem by now. If not, just ensure there is a config object associated with every fetch call, a simple

```
{
method: "GET"
}
```

will do.